# What is the quickest way to evenly slice chicken breasts for jerky?

Tags: chicken, meat, chicken-breast, dehydrating, jerky

I am using a dehydrator to make jerky from boneless skinless chicken breasts.  Cutting these by hand is too time-consuming and produces uneven pieces which finish dehydrating at various times.  What is the quickest way to remove the fat from and evenly slice chicken breasts for jerky?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Freeze the breasts, then use a mandoline to make even slices. (If you have access to a deli slicer with its rotary blade, that would be even faster; however, a mandoline slicer is more typical in a home kitchen.)

The freezing keeps the relatively small pieces of meat stable so they will slice more evenly. Frozen breasts slice more evenly even by hand in my experience.

Comment: I do this too. I will say that you want the meat partially frozen though. If it's rock hard there will be no slicing.

Comment: You're missing a closing parenthesis.